# generate schema file during build for hibernate 4.1.2

Tags: hibernate, maven

I'm currently using Hibernate 3.6.9 with hibernate3-maven-plugin. I use the goal hbm2ddl to generate an sql schema file.

The plugin does not support Hibernate 4.1.2. How do I generate a schema file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hibernate3-maven-plugin` just calls [SchemaExport](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html) to generate the schema file.  Why not manually call it by ourself?

Example :

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();

Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test"); 
properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
config.setProperties(properties);

config.addAnnotatedClass(MyMappedPojo1.class);
config.addAnnotatedClass(MyMappedPojo2.class);
..................

SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(config);

/**Just dump the schema SQLs to the console , but not execute them ***/
schemaExport.create(true, false);
```